# forest - Precise vertical adjustment of the text of extra additional nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I would like to adjust the vertical positions of the times symbol in the picture above.

[image]

Here is the code used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
  for tree = {math content},
  where n children = 0 {tier = word} {}
  [243
    [3   [3^1]]
    [81
      [9   [3^2]]       
      [9   [3^2]]
    ]
  ]
  \path (!11)  -- (!211) node[midway]{$\times$};
  \path (!211) -- (!221) node[midway]{$\times$};
\end{forest}

But we must have :

$3^1 \times 3^2 \times 3^2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Prehaps using the `base` anchor? As in `\path (!11.base) -- (!211.base) node[midway,anchor=base]{$\times$};`

Comment: Good point. I don't even try to play withe forest nodes... :-( Thanks. Post an answer such as to keep my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could use the `base` anchor. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
  for tree = {math content},
  where n children = 0 {tier = word} {}
  [343
    [3   [3^1]]
    [81
      [9   [3^2]]       
      [9   [3^2]]
    ]
  ]
  \path (!11.base)  -- (!211.base) node[midway,anchor=base]{$\times$};
  \path (!211.base) -- (!221.base) node[midway,anchor=base]{$\times$};
\end{forest}

But we must have:

$3^1 \times 3^2 \times 3^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]